# EEGrunt: Error name is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-analysis, nameerror

This might be a very beginner level error.

It says:

```
 NameError in line 16 that'start' is not defined.
```

I am running a code for `OpenBCI` called `EEGrunt`, which is used to analyse EEG data. I am not sure how should I define start or stop for this particular program

```
import EEGrunt
source = 'openbci'
path = 'C:/Users/Vedant/Desktop/Pygaze/OpenBCI_2/application.windows64/SavedData/'
filename = 'OpenBCI-RAW-2016-11-28_16-23-14.txt'
session_title = "OpenBCI EEGrunt Test Data"
EEG = EEGrunt.EEGrunt(path, filename, source, session_title)
EEG.plot = 'show'
EEG.load_data()
for channel in EEG.channels:
   EEG.load_channel(channel)
   print("Processing channel "+ str(EEG.channel))
   EEG.remove_dc_offset()
   EEG.notch_mains_interference()
   EEG.signalplot()
   EEG.get_spectrum_data()
   EEG.data = EEG.bandpass(start, stop)
   EEG.spectrogram()
   EEG.plot_band_power(8,12,"Alpha")
   EEG.plot_spectrum_avg_fft()
   EEG.showplots()
```

Comment: Well, indeed, neither `start` nor `stop` are defined. Where are you expecting them to come from?

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation. What is inside the `for` loop?

Comment: sorry i would just indent properly

Comment: The issue was how should i define start and stop in the case of this program

Comment: Don't know. What do you want them to be?

Comment: I assume you should set `start` and `stop` to appropriate low and high frequency values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. According to the owners of the project:

> That line should be commented out by default.
>
> The bandpass function takes the data and applies a butterworth
>   bandpass filter. The start and stop arguments set the frequency range
>   to bandpass, in Hertz. But it’s optional: most of the time it’s not
>   used, and it shouldn’t stop the program from running.

https://github.com/curiositry/EEGrunt/issues/11

Comment: Thank you so much would try commenting it out :)